# how to multithread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronize

I have to multithread a method that runs a code in the batches of 1000 . I need to give these batches to different threads .

Currently i have spawn 3 threads but all 3 are picking the 1st batch of 1000 . 
I want that the other batches should not pick the same batch instead pick the other batch .

Please help and give suggestions.

Comment: Could you please show [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use an ExecutorService

```
int numberOfTasks = ....
int batchSize = 1000;
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i += batchSize) {
    final int start = i;
    final int last = Math.min(i + batchSize, numberOfTasks);
    es.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int j = start; j < last; j++)
                System.out.println(j); // do something with j
        }
    });
}
es.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to synchronize the access to the list of jobs in the batch. ("Synchronize" essentially means "make sure the threads aware of potential race-conditions". In most scenarios this means "let some method be executed by a single thread at a time".)

This is easiest solved using the `java.util.concurrent` package. Have a look at the various implementations of [`BlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for instance [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) or [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

Answer (score 3):

Put the batches in a [`BlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and make your worker threads to take the batches from the queue.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `lock` or a `mutex` when retrieving the batch. That way, the threads can't access the critical section at the same time and can't accidentally access the same batch.

I'm assuming you're removing a batch once it was picked by a thread.

EDIT: aioobe and jonas' answers are better, use that. This is an alternative. :)