# Using parallelism to generate a large number of PDF files in UNIX

Tags: java, unix, jasper-reports

So ultimately I need to write a large number of PDFs (40,000) on disk on a UNIX server and I'm trying to figure out a way to do this efficiently(faster/consuming less memory).

I have been using JasperReports to create a template which recieves as Parameters(meaning the report doesn't hit the database) all the information needed on the report.

Then I have a simple Java app that queries the DB and brings the dataset and for each record it fills the .jasper and writes the PDF to disk.

Now this works fine for a couple hundred of records but I'm thinking that it won't work for production where the number scales to 40.000 records and the output of the process will be an equal number of PDF files. Doing some testing I'm estimating that the process will take at least 3 hours and I'm also beginning to worry about memory consumption.

So what I would like to know is if there is an efficient way to do this:

- Should I be using parallelism/multiple threads for this process?
- Can anyone point me towards a knonw pattern/example for this kind of job?

Thank you for your time

Comment: You say "faster/less memory". It is often difficult to achieve both. Also, See the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just a note, multiple threads != faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use less memory and use multithreading to render different PDFs, each thread would allocate memory to work on its PDF, memory usage would be linear to the number of threads.
It's a completely different story if you can work on the same PDF(same data) with multiple threads, but i don't think it would easy to do  since thread would require frequent synchronization making multithreading meaningless.

It will be trivial to implement multithreading if they don't need to share any information, you can just implement [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, create new thread passing the implementation of Runnable, and wait them to end with [Thread.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()).

If i were you i would use [jasper virtualizer](https://itblackbelt.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/generating-huge-reports-in-jasperreports/) to load only a part of the dataset at the time, this would probably allow you to use multiple threads.

Comment: Yes this is what I ended up doing but instead of handling thread creation myself I'm using the ExecutoService as described on this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/7966732/4524542. Thanks for your answer, I'll look into Jasper Virtualizer for handling the large dataset.